# What is the probability of getting sum exactly n as total for throwing x dice?

Tags: probability

"What is the probability of getting sum exactly 420 as total for throwing 100 dice?" is the actual question. But maybe I can modify it as title?

Just give me directions by which I can be able to solve the problem.
How can we calculate such probability of large dices?
Do I need to go with theoretical probability to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @BigyanDahal:  You are clearly not a native English speaker and have many ungrammatical and unclear statements.  "...throwing 100 number of dice" is ungrammatical... it should be "throwing 100 dice."  I've tried to correct your grammar, but you keep (mis)editing your post, overwriting correct grammar and clarity.  I give up trying to help you.

Comment: Thanks @DavidG.Stork. I hope my question is understandable now and could get the answer.

Comment: It is NOT, for instance "throwing 100 number of dice" (as I've fixed before).  I would clarify your question and fix the ungrammatical phrases (as I have done at least six times), but you keep making changes back to incorrect, ungrammatical, and misleading sentences, so I will not help you.  If you know a native English speaker, have him or her fix your errors before you repost.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I am new to this site and do not know most of the rules. I think I will read the rules first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So rephrasing your question, you are asking how many solutions there are to the following equation:
$$x_1+x_2+...+x_{100}=420$$
Where $1<=x<=6$.

This equation equals to:
$$y_1+y_2+...+y_{100}=320$$
Where $0<=y<=5$

Then, see this solution - [How many solutions for an equation with simple restrictions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649039/how-many-solutions-for-an-equation-with-simple-restrictions)